# How to define an iterator class for my class?

Tags: python, iterator, networkx

I have created a wrapper class `Graph` inside of which `networkx`-based graphs are created. However, the objects of this class are not iterable. To resolve the issue, I do know that I have to define `__iter__()` function, for my `Graph` class, in which an instance of an iterator class, say, `GraphIterator` is called. I just checked some samples of various `__next__()` function, although I don't know how I should define the `__next__()` function of my class. Any help is then appreciated.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Graph():
    def __init__(self, nodes=None, raw_edges=None, source_node=None, target_node=None):
        G = nx.Graph(source_node=None, target_node=None)
        G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
        G.add_edges_from([self.create_edge(raw_edge) for raw_edge in raw_edges])
        G.graph["source_node"] = self.assign_source_node(source_node, G.nodes)
        G.graph["target_node"] = self.assign_target_node(target_node, G.nodes)

    def __iter__(self):
        return GraphIterator(self)

    def create_edge(self, raw_edge):
        return [raw_edge[0], raw_edge[1], {'attr': raw_edge[2]}]

    def assign_source_node(self, source_node, node_list):
        if (int(source_node) in node_list):
            return source_node
        else:
            raise ValueError("Source node assignnmet is problematic!")

    def assign_target_node(self, target_node, node_list):
        if (int(target_node) in node_list):
            return target_node
        else:
            raise ValueError("Target node assignnmet is problematic!")


class GraphIterator:
   def __init__(self, graph):
       self._graph = graph
       self._index = 0
   def __next__(self):
       pass

def main():
    nodes = [1,2,3]
    raw_edges = [[1,2,1],[1,3,1],[2,3,1]]
    source_node = "1"
    target_node = "3"

    graph = Graph(nodes, raw_edges, source_node, target_node)

    nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True, font_weight="bold")
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Doesn’t the networkx Graph already [provide an iterator?](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.__iter__.html)

Comment: @Mark: The link says it iterates over nodes (not edges, I suppose). As well, I don't know how it can be used in my context.

Comment: If you need to iterate over edges, `for edge in G.edges` works.

Comment: Also, you should probably go read about generators. Writing iterators manually is rarely the best option.